# Two-step method resolution with inheritance and generic constraints

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I've encountered something quite surprising when using generic constraints with inheritance. I have an overloaded methods `Foo` that differ with parameter - either base or derived class instance. In both cases it's generally just passing the instance to the second pair of overloaded methods - `Bar`.

When I call `Foo` with base class instance, `Bar` overload for the base class is called. When I call `Foo` with derived class instance, `Bar` overload for the derived class is called. This is clear and expected.

But when I tried to merge `Foo` methods into single one `GenericFoo` that use generics and constraints, methods are resolved differently - T is resolved correctly, but only base-class overload of `Bar` is called.

```
public class Animal { }
public class Cat : Animal { }

public class AnimalProcessor
{
    public static void Foo(Animal obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo(Animal)");
        Bar(obj);
    }

    public static void Foo(Cat obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo(Cat)");
        Bar(obj);
    }

    // new generic method to replace the two above
    public static void GenericFoo<T>(T obj)
        where T : Animal
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo(generic)");
        Bar(obj);
    }

    public static void Bar(Animal obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar(Animal)");
    }

    public static void Bar(Cat obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar(Cat)");
    }
}
```

Testing code - two first cases for non-generic old methods, two last for new generic method.

```
Console.WriteLine("Animal()");
AnimalProcessor.Foo(new Animal());
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Cat()"); 
AnimalProcessor.Foo(new Cat());
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Animal()");
AnimalProcessor.GenericFoo(new Animal());
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Cat()"); 
AnimalProcessor.GenericFoo(new Cat());
Console.ReadLine();
```

And the result - note the difference in type resolved in `Bar`:

```
Animal()
Foo(Animal)
Bar(Animal)

Cat()
Foo(Cat)
Bar(Cat)

Animal()
Foo(generic)
Bar(Animal)

Cat()
Foo(generic)
Bar(Animal)
```

It looks like the compiler binds all calls from `GenericFoo` to the least specific overload, even if all more specific-typed calls are known at compile time. Why is that, what is the reason for such behaviour? Which part of specs defines this?

Comment: Just as a side note, to force a type, you could do `AnimalProcessor.GenericFoo<Cat>(new Cat());` although +1 as I'm interested in the answer too.

Comment: "…even if all more specific-typed calls are known at compile time." This is a false assumption. The compiler can't know what callers will consume the dll it produces, as they may well come from other assemblies.

Comment: Sure, for all not known implementations, `Animal` is a safe fallback. But in my case `Cat` is known at compile time and is known to be used as `T`. Why is this not resolved?

Comment: compiling Foo(Cat, the compiler knows obj is of type Cat. When compiling Foo<T>, obj could be Cat, Dog, or Animal. It doesn't know at compile time, and as it has no control over who executes this method in the assembly, can't make assumptions for what exact type obj will be at runtime. The methods aren't virtual, so it binds to Animal

Comment: Generics are not templates.  Generic methods are compiled once and their behavior is for the 'most generic' case (in this case, Animal.)  This is different from C++ style templating, where the template is compiled separately for each specialization by type.

Comment: @DanBryant, can you post this as an answer? Comparison with templates explained me the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per OP's request, comment re-posted as answer:

Generics are not templates. Generic methods are compiled once and their behavior is for the 'most generic' case (in this case, Animal.) This is different from C++ style templating, where the template is compiled separately for each specialization by type.

Answer (score 2):

The generic C# method is compiled into a generic IL method. And in IL, you have to explicitly specify which overload you are calling. So there is no simple way how the compiler could have done this. (There is complicated way: run a mini-compiler that chooses the overload at this point dynamically, which is what `dynamic` does.)

If you want this behavior, one option would be to make `Bar()` a virtual method on `Animal`. Another option would be using `dynamic`.